# Average length of chord of circle - definite integral

Tags: geometry, definite-integrals, circles

> Given a circle C of radius a, and a diameter AB of C.  Chords are drawn perpendicular to AB, intercepting equal arcs along the circumference of C.  Find the limit of the average of the lengths of these chords, as the number of chords tends to infinity.

I can find the average lengths of the chords that intercept equal segments along AB:
$$L_{ave}= 2*\frac{1}{a}\int_{0}^{a}\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\quad dx = 2*\frac{1}{a}* \frac{1}{4}\pi a^2 = \frac{\pi a}{2}$$

This is straightforward since $dx$ is invariable.

However, when  solving the problem for chords intercepting equal arc segments, then $dx$ varies across the diameter of the circle.  I was trying to set it up as a function of $sin$ or $cos$, but then I have both x and an angle as variables.  Any hints on how to approach this?

Comment: Make it a trig function of $n$, the number of chords.

Comment: Fun fact: For spheres these two notions (planar cuts with equal distance along the diameter, and planar cuts with equal surface area) coincide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality assume the circle is of radius 1 and divided by $n$ chords into $2n$ arcs. The required limit is then the Riemann sum
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}2\sin\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}$$
which is thus equivalent to the integral
$$\int_0^12\sin\pi x\,dx=\frac4\pi$$
Therefore, for a circle of radius $a$, the average length is $\frac{4a}\pi$.

Comment: I find it odd that you didn't comment on the difference in the results.  If we are seeking the true average cord length it must be the height of a rectangle with the same area as the circle, and a length equal to its diameter.  That points to your first answer as the correct one for that question.

Comment: @D.Ennis I only have _one_ answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Depends which random variable you decide to average on.
In one case you can average over the distance of the chord from the center which gives you R*pi/2 and in the other case you can average over the angle between the two extremities of the chord which gives you 4*R/pi.

One considers a uniform distribution of a distance between 0 to R (or - R to R) the other a uniform distribution of an angle between 0 to 2*pi.

Both distributions are not equivalent since there is a cos() transformation from one random variable to the other.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).